# Driver memory not getting cleaned up in Spark Structured Streaming

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

I am using my Spark Structured Streaming job to perform my ETL in AWS platform
My Driver memory is not getting cleared-up. The job is reading the events from Kinesis and writing to S3
Below are the my Spark configurations. Also attaching screenshot containing Driver JVM heap usage graph for reference (1 means 100%)

```
spark.cleaner.periodicGC.interval=1min
spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-XX:+UseG1GC
spark.cleaner.referenceTracking.blocking=false
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

We had seen this when Spark UI in yarn had lots of jobs being listed. We limited the no.of jobs (for ex. to 100 etc), tasks and stages shown in UI. This helped decrease driver memory usage. You can give a try

```
spark.ui.retainedJobs, spark.ui.retainedStages,spark.ui.retainedTasks, spark.worker.ui.retainedExecutors,spark.worker.ui.retainedDrivers, spark.sql.ui.retainedExecutions,spark.streaming.ui.retainedBatches
```

Comment: Thanks Vindhya. I tried your recommendation. This too did not worked

Comment: Can you add the code snippet to understand what exactly being done